# Activate logging in electron-builder NSIS Installer

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I am trying to generate the log for NSIS installer for my electron app. To achieve it I have created a file 'logging.nsh' to define the LogSet and LogText macros.
Below is the code for logging.nsh file:

```
!define LogSet "!insertmacro LogSetMacro"
!macro LogSetMacro SETTING
  !ifdef ENABLE_LOGGING
    LogSet ${SETTING}
  !endif
!macroend

!define LogText "!insertmacro LogTextMacro"
!macro LogTextMacro INPUT_TEXT
  !ifdef ENABLE_LOGGING
    LogSet ${INPUT_TEXT}
  !endif
!macroend
```

installer.nsh

```
!define ENABLE_LOGGING
!include "logging.nsh"

!macro preInit
     SetOutPath $INSTDIR
     ${LogSet} on
!macroend
```

When I build my installer I am getting the error saying `**NSIS_CONFIG_LOG is not defined**` On checking the NSIS forum I figured out NSIS_CONFIG_LOG should be defined at compile time for LogSet to work. Reference: http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/LogSet. I am not able to figure out how I can define NSIS_CONFIG_LOG at compile time for my electron app. 
Any Suggestions will be appreciated
Or if there is any other way I can generate logs for my electron app's NSIS installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSIS itself (makensis and the stubs) needs to be built with the logging turned on for `LogSet` to work.

You can [download a logging build](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Special_Builds) from the NSIS website.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I did observe this custom build for logging but not understanding how I can integrate it with electron-builder?

Comment: I don't know anything about electron-builder but I assume it bundles the NSIS files in its folder. Just replace those with the files from the logging download.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have one more question. the log generated is pretty big, so can I generate a verbose log?

Comment: Verbose would mean even more output but no, I don't thing you can change which items it logs.